# How can I add an image in a format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this format and I want to add the image in that format

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lBRG.png]

My code is:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <li>
        <span class="product-thumb-info">
            <button class="btn" style="width:100%; color: white; background:#0088cc" onclick="document.getElementById('getFile').click()">Add Image</button>
            <input type='file' id="getFile" style="display:none">
            <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="img/products/product-10.jpg">
        </span>
    </li>    
</div>
```

Comment: Add an image? Why isn't the `<img />` tag you have there working?

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to add the image in the attached format when I choose the image.

Comment: So when the user selects a file from their local machine, you want to display it in place of the existing `<img />`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need

Comment: Look at this and make sure the link is correct. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple upload image with format your html, you can refer it.

```js
 $("#getFile").change(function () {
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            }
        });
        
   function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        $('.img-responsive').attr('src', e.target.result);

    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-4">
    <li>
        <span class="product-thumb-info">
            <button class="btn" style="width:100%; color: white; background:#0088cc" onclick="document.getElementById('getFile').click()">Add Image</button>
            <input type='file' id="getFile" style="display:none">
            <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="">
        </span>
    </li>    
</div>
```